# "In front" mesh parameter/attribute activate short cut?

Tags: retopology

Hey english is not my native language, is there a shortcut and keybind to quickly set an object in "in front" mod.
Im asking because i m doing some retopology and i already use alt z, shift alt z to see better but if there is an additional way of viewing my objects i take it.

PS : Perfect thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set a shortcut nearly any operator or menu item  and/or add it to your quick favorites menu, by right clicking it and selecting the relevant option.

[image]